# AttributeError: Line2D.set() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data2'. Not sure why I am getting this error

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I am trying to run this code: https://github.com/dgnzlz/Capstone_AWS_DeepRacer/blob/master/Compute_Speed_And_Actions/RaceLine_Speed_ActionSpace.ipynb

and when I am trying to Input 16 for my own track I am facing the above error. I did check with the size of array and the output of data and data 2

---

Data 1

0      -15.779266
1        5.370969
2       -3.312167
3        0.350266
4       -4.806697
...
1417    23.961580
1418   -17.357656
1419     3.392454
1420     3.036370
1421     1.961139

Name: steering, Length: 1422, dtype: float64

Size: 1422

---

Data 2

0       2.231035
1       1.790297
2       1.586387
3       2.084898
4       2.766869
...
1417    1.644355
1418    2.422821
1419    1.790297
1420    1.308018
1421    2.918526
Name: velocity, Length: 1422, dtype: float64
Size: 1422

I am not sure why I should be getting this error then.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
ax = sns.kdeplot(x=all_actions_norm_less["steering"], y=all_actions_norm_less["velocity"])
ax.invert_xaxis()

As new seaborn now modify "data" and "data2" into "x" and "y"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).